# How to verify if a word has valid syllables or not?

Tags: algorithm

I need to be able to process one word or words and verify that it has valid syllables. There are some syllabification rules that could be used:

```
V CV VC CVC CCV CCCV CVCC
```

where V is a vowel and C is a consonant. e.g.,

```
pronunciation (5 Pro-nun-ci-a-tion; CCV-CVC-CV-V-CVC)
```

Or is there a simple code that can be used, or a library in c++? In class we're talking about binary search trees, hash tables, etc, but i can't really see the relation. Any help would appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `Pro-nun-ci-a-tion; CV-CVC-CV-V-CVC` should it not be `Pro-nun-ci-a-tion; CCV-CVC-CV-V-CVC`

Comment: This could be of help: In case of `CCCV`, the first C can only be `s` while the last C can be only `r` or `l`. In the case of CCV, either the first C is `s` or the second C is `r` or `l`. (Double check this). In the case of `V`, I think it comes only if the previous syllable ended in `V`. The ones ending in `C` probably take their `C` if that `C` can't belong to the next syllable (for example if it is not `s` and there is another `C` after it which is not `r` or `l`). Perhaps with a couple letters of look-ahead, you can devise the rules and find the syllables in one pass.

Comment: In English, as many consonants as possible should be grouped with the vowel that follows them, without creating impossible clusters. The list of allowed and forbidden consonant clusters can be looked up (@Shahbaz has some of the rules but not all). The difficulty is determining where the consonants and vowels are (i.e. letters-to-sounds conversion). See e.g. [here](http://clas.mq.edu.au/phonetics/phonology/syllable/syll_phonotactic.html). Other languages may have totally different rules.

Comment: Given the context, "in class we are...", I suspect this is an academic exercise. The word pronunciation would be represented by the string "CCVCVCCVVCVVC" to be parsed into sub-strings from a set into CCV-CVC-CV-V-CVVC without regard to what the actual consonants and vowels are. If so, both shri and ztzu would be equally valid CCCV patterns for the purpose of the exercise. In other words, I interpret the question as does the regular expression ""^((V)|(CV)|(VC)|(CVC)|(CCV)|(CCCV)|(CVCC))*$" match the input, e.g. "CCVCVCCVVCVVC"? If so, there is your hint at one possible solution path.

Comment: I would argue that there isn't a notion of valid syllable, just as there is no way to define a valid English word without exhaustive enumeration. Therefore, as @A.Webb suggests, this is most likely an exercise, where the notion of validity is probably defined in some simplified fashion, in which case it would make sense include that notion in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever we have collected a full pattern-string, we can either discard it and begin collecting to a new pattern-string, or keep it and try to get a longer pattern-string. We don't know in advance (without examining the rest of the input-string), whether we should keep or discard the current string, so we need to keep both possibilities in mind.

We can build a state machine that can keep track of this for us. The base-states are identified by the sequence of characters we have examined so far:

```python
State   C           V
""      {"C"}       {"V",""}
"C"     {"CC"}      {"CV",""}
"CC"    {"CCC"}     {""}
"CCC"   {}          {""}
"CV"    {"CVC",""}  {}
"CVC"   {""}        {}
"V"     {""}        {}
```

Since we don't always know which action to take, we can be in several possible states at once. Those sets of possible states form super-states:

```python
Index   Super-state        C    V
    0   {}                 0    0   Fail 
    1   {""}               2    9   Accept 
    2   {"C"}              3    8
    3   {"CC"}             4    1
    4   {"CCC"}            0    1
    5   {"","C"}           6   13   Accept
    6   {"C","CC"}         7    8
    7   {"CC","CCC"}       4    1
    8   {"","CV"}         12    9   Accept
    9   {"","V"}           5    9   Accept
   10   {"","C","CC"}     11   13   Accept
   11   {"C","CC","CCC"}   7    8
   12   {"","C","CVC"}    10   13   Accept
   13   {"","CV","V"}     12    9   Accept
```

The transitions are between super-states. Each member of the super-state is advanced with the same symbol. All members without such transition are discarded. If a member has two possible destinations, both are added to the new super-state.

You might notice that some rows are very similar. Super-state 3 and 7 have the same transitions. As are 6 and 11, and 8 and 13. You could collapse those into one state each, and update the indices. I'm not going to demonstrate that here.

This could easily be encoded into a programming language:

```cs
//                    index = 0  1  2  3  4   5  6  7   8  9  10  11  12  13
int[] consonant = new int[] { 0, 2, 3, 4, 0,  6, 7, 4, 12, 5, 11,  7, 10, 12 };
int[] vocal = new int[] {     0, 9, 8, 1, 1, 13, 8, 1,  9, 9, 13,  8, 13,  9 };
int[] accept = new int[] {    0, 1, 0, 0, 0,  1, 0, 0,  1, 1,  1,  0,  1,  1 };
int startState = 1;
int failState = 0;

bool CheckWord(string word)
{
    int state = startState;
    foreach (char c in word)
    {
        if (IsVocal(c))
        {
            state = vocal[state];
        }
        else if (IsConsonant(c))
        {
            state = consonant[state];
        }
        if (state == failState) return false;
    }
    return accept[state] != 0;
}
```

**Example:**

```cs
> CheckWord("pronunciation")
true

> CheckWord("pronunciationn")
false
```

Comment: +1 For a good description of how to build a state machine for this particular regular expression. See also http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html for how to implement regular expressions in state machines in general.